# Pay Pal Recurring Payment Integration

Tags: paypal

I have a site which will receive money from customers in a regular period(Say once in a week). I am storing my clients details in my database and i want withdraw money form my customers account with out prompting them for authentication every time.The amount will be vary with respect to the customers. How can i do this with pay pal?Do i need to buy pay pal pro for implementing this.I read some docs related to recurring payments and reference payment services of pay pal, but i don't know how it will work when my business pay pal account registered in Australia.

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 1):

We recently (Jan 2013) implemented a recurring payment integration with PalPal for an Australian site (paypal account).

We used;

- PayFlow Pro (doc:
  https://www.x.com/sites/default/files/payflowgateway_guide.pdf)
- Recurring Payments module (doc: https://www.x.com/sites/default/files/pp_payflowpro_recurringbilling_guide.pdf)

I can't say the experience was a pleasant one, a lot of reading, phone calls to support, and hair-pulling - but we got there in the end.

Depending on your situation I would suggest looking at Pin Payment Gateway (https://pin.net.au/) as an alternative.

Comment: also I was just recommended BrainTree as a good alternative https://www.braintreepayments.com/ - they're meant to handle recurring payments very well

Comment: could you possibly expand on what you did? We are going through the same issue right now - we are using NVP API CreateRecurringPaymentsProfile.

Answer (score 0):

**You can use PayPal Recurring Payment method for this.**

As you said you do not want you want to withdraw money from there account without authenticating them again, you have to create a subscription profile of customer on paypal via an **NVP API** (**CreateRecurringPaymentsProfile**).

After you get the Subscription ID of the customer with a success message you need not to store  customers details (card details), which is also illegal to do so.

While calling the

> CreateRecurringPaymentsProfile method of API

You need to set the following fields.

```
BILLINGPERIOD = MONTH or DAY (according to your need)

BILLINGFREQUENCY = 2 (means after 2 BILLINGPERIOD )

TOTALBILLINGCYCLES = 10
```

**For Example :** if BILLINGPERIOD = MONTH & BILLINGFREQUENCY = 2 & TOTALBILLINGCYCLES = 10 then automatic payment will occur after every 2 months till 10 payment cycles are completed.

```
You can also find the example code here :
http://paypal.github.io/sample-apps/
```